# Overlay on Image in Windows 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing a Windows 8.1 universal app.

i am using images in my grid view which is again bounded to some application model.
Now i want to add overlay(decorator) on images depending on some condition in my model.
is it possible to do so ?

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Put any control you like on top of the Image controls. What have you tried so far? What is your specific problem?

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the reply...i have an image over which i want to put up an overlay image at the right bottom of the parent image.

Comment: Put two Image controls in a common Grid?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already do it, you should put your image in the GridView.ItemTemplate. And then add your overlay whith the visibility set depending on the condition with the help of a converter.

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
         <Image Source="{Binding YourSource}" /> <!-- your image -->
         <Image Source="{Binding OverlaySource}" Visibility="{Binding IsOverlayVisibleBoolean, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

And your converter :

```
public class BooleanToVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   {
      if (value is Boolean)
         return (Boolean)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

      return Visibility.Collapsed;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```